# WP 8.1 - Custom checkbox in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I don't know how I can customize the checkboxes in my multiselect listview in windows phone.

I want to change the box and the selected image to my own one (two images, one for the box, one for the check)

Here the code of the ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="ListFriendView" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFriend,Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Style="{StaticResource FriendPickerList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" >
                            <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" StrokeThickness="3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/holder-avatar.png"/>
                                </Ellipse.Stroke>
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ProfilePicture,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel  Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" Style="{StaticResource CarterOne}" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LName}" Style="{StaticResource CarterOne}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CarterOne}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                 <Run Text="{Binding Points}"/>
                                 <Run Text="  pts"/>
                            </TextBlock>

                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

I'm trying to do it with blend, but I only see the itemPresenter...

[image]

If somebody already do this kind of things...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is style generated

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle2" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMargin}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckboxPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxTiltContainer"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="ListMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="NoMultiSelect"/>
                                        <VisualTransition From="NoMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="ListMultiSelect"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoMultiSelect"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ListMultiSelect">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTranslateX}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="GridMultiSelect">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderModeStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="ReorderEnabled" GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="ReorderDisabled"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ReorderEnabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Reorderable">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ReorderDisabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                                <Border x:Name="CheckboxTiltContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMultiselectCheckBoxMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Border x:Name="CheckboxOuterContainer">
                                        <Border.Clip>
                                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,25.5,25.5"/>
                                        </Border.Clip>
                                        <Grid x:Name="CheckboxContainer">
                                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform" X="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentOffsetX}"/>
                                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="25.5" Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" Width="25.5"/>
                                            <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18.5"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                    <Border x:Name="TiltContainer">
                                        <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="SelectedBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMultiselectBorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34">
                                        <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="SelectedGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="14.5" Margin="0,1,1,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

You have to edit following style snippet extracted from above style to put images

```
<Border x:Name="CheckboxTiltContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMultiselectCheckBoxMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Border x:Name="CheckboxOuterContainer">
                                        <Border.Clip>
                                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,25.5,25.5"/>
                                        </Border.Clip>
                                        <Grid x:Name="CheckboxContainer">
                                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform" X="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentOffsetX}"/>
                                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="25.5" Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" Width="25.5"/>
                                            <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18.5"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
```

Comment: Thanks :D, very helpfull

Comment: Already done ;à, last thing, as you can see in my code i have a spefic display for the data binding... this is no working anymore with the new template :/ do you know why ?

Comment: First thing you have not accepted the answer yet. Second thing I haven't understood your problem. Which data? Or whole data template is not visible?

Comment: sorry i clicked, but did not work. Now normally is accepted. And my problem is if I put grid and grid column in the datatemplate, this not working... the grid column are not apply

Comment: Why are you declaring 5 columns when you're just using 3. Any reason? And wat do you mean by grid column are not applying? Could you attach a screenshot or something

Comment: This is not related to the new item template, so thanks for your help I will find a solution. many thanks for your time